# Implementing Airflow with real scripts

Tags: airflow

I set up an Airflow server successfully. I want to run some test jobs but I am having trouble finding beginner guides which fit into what I am trying to do.

Current status:

- Python scripts to download files from SFTP (any file which does not exist on local machine) or create a file from a queryout
- Pandas scripts to read the data into memory, modify it in some way to prepare it for the database (look for new dimensions, remap, add calculations). Load data to appropriate table in database. Send email summaries (pandas to_html)

The logic I have for most of my scripts is based on if the file has not been processed, then process it. 'Processed' files are either organized by filename in a db table, or I move the file to a special processed folder.

The other logic I have is based on the date in the filename. I compare the dates of files which exist versus dates which should exist (a range of dates). If the file does not exist, then I create it (usually a BCP or PSQL query).

Do I just have Airflow run these .py files? Or should I alter my scripts to use some of the Airflow parameters/jinja templating?

I almost feel like I could use the BashOperator for almost everything. Would this work

```
dag_input = sys.argv[1]

def alter_table(query, engine=pg_engine):
    fake_conn = engine.raw_connection()
    fake_cur = fake_conn.cursor()
    fake_cur.execute(query)
    fake_conn.commit()
    fake_cur.close()

query_list = [
              f'SELECT * from table_1 where report_date = \'{dag_input}\'',
              f'SELECT * from table_2 where report_date = \'{dag_input}\'',
]

for value in query_list:
    alter_table(value)
```

Then the dag would be something like this, with an airflow parameter used for the sys.argv?

```
templated_command = """
        python download_raw.py "{{ ds }}"
"""

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='download_raw',
    bash_command=templated_command,
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the code for this task is in python, I would use a PythonOperator.

Put a method in download_raw.py that takes **kwargs as parameters and you have access to everything in the context.

```py
from download_raw import my_func

t3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='download_raw',
    python_callable=my_func,
    dag=dag)


#inside download_raw.py

def my_func(**kwargs):
    context = kwargs
    ds = context['ds']
    ... (do your logic here)
```

I would do it like this or your bash command could get hideous when several pieces of the context.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a concrete example? Does ds refer to the execution date? I think my issue now is that I have so much code, some of it years old, which has been running daily. I am hesitant to make a lot of changes unless it really makes sense to do so.

Comment: This is a pretty concrete example. In your post you specified using {{ ds }} which is the execution date, and why I used it in my example. For a more comprehensive list of what you have access to with the context object see here: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#macros

You probably don't need to make a lot of changes to your code, but you will need to add an entry point, which in my example is my_func. In this function, you can take ds (or anything else in the context), reformat how you like and pass it on to your existing program logic.

Comment: FYI, almost a year later but I am using the method you outlined here.